# Connect Docker-container by Unit-socket

Tags: docker, sockets, dockerfile

I try to connect Docker-container with inner-resource by Unit-socket.

For this purpose I add to Dockerfile the following command:

```
 RUN -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

But on the stage of docker build I receive: /bin/sh: illegal option - 
ERROR: Service 'webapp' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432' returned a non-zero code: 2

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`RUN` instruction in a Dockerfile is used to run a command inside container during build, not to run your container. Refer to it's [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run).

To make a Unix socket available inside your container, specify a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container) when you start the container:

```
docker run -v /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 yourapp:latest
```

This will make `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` socket on your host available inside the container.

You may also specify different host and container path:

```
docker run -v /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432:/tmp/postgresql yourapp:latest
```

> Note: `/var/run/docker.sock` is used to communicate with Docker
>   daemon. Be careful with it, since access to Docker daemon provides root access to your machine.

Comment: And could you clear me another one aspect of this problem? Do I understand correctly, that I must run this command on the machine, where database with PGSQL.5432 . is mounted?   I build my container, up by docker-compose and push at my local machine, then it migrates on remote server with database (with unix-socket)

Comment: Glad to help! 
Yes, you must run your container on the same machine as your database. There’s a bunch of ways to do that: either by building locally and transferring images to remote host, or configuring remote access to Docker daemon. Take a look at answers here: https://serverfault.com/q/809460